# Separação das responsabilidades da aplicação

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

gostaria de tirar uma dúvida sobre a separação de responsabilidades em uma aplicação. Eu criei uma API em Node para praticar os conceitos e estou refatorando o código para que atenda as melhores práticas, então eu tenho a seguinte estrutura:

> Rota

```
routes.post('/transactions/create', createTransaction);
```

> Controlador

```
const createTransaction = async (request, response) => {
    const { date, category, description, value, type } = request.body;
    const day = date.slice(8);
    const month = date.slice(5, -3);
    const year = date.slice(0, -6);
    const yearMonth = year + "-" + month;
    const yearMonthDay = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

    try {
        const newTransaction = await transactionsRepository.createTransaction(description, category, value, day, month,
        year, yearMonth, yearMonthDay, type);
        response.status(200).send(newTransaction);
    } catch (e) {
        response.status(500).send( { message: 'Failed to load transaction'} );
    }
}
```

> Repositório

```
const createTransaction = async (description, category, value, day, month, year, yearMonth, yearMonthDay, type) => {
    const newTransaction = await transactionsModel.insertMany({
      description,
      value,
      category,
      year,
      month,
      day,
      yearMonth,
      yearMonthDay,
      type,
    });

    return newTransaction;
};
```

Como se pode ver no controlador, ele atualmente recebe uma data e trata ela para que seja enviada para o banco. Eu li que deveria haver uma camada de serviço entre o controlador e o repositório para regras de negócio.

Minha dúvida é, esse tratamento da data deveria ficar na camada  de serviço ou deveria ficar num pacote utils ou helpers? Estou com dúvida o que a camada de serviço deve conter.

Comment: se tiver uma camada "de negócio" pode tratar regras de negócio lá. Pense sempre no contexto de "qual o propósito" do que se quer fazer. Peguemos o exemplo da data, imagina que a data precisa ter um formato "aaaa-mm-dd" para ser exibida. Se é uma regra "de exibição" deve ser feita nessa camada. Agora imagina que seja uma regra de modelo de dados, deve ser feita lá (repository), e assim por diante. O objetivo das camadas é isolar responsabilidades é fazer manutenção nessa parte isoladamente e testá-la isoladamente, por isso veja o propósito "da regra" para ver em qual camada ela fica melhor

Comment: se tiver uma única regra, pode criar uma classe para isso, um helper algo assim. Ao criar uma camada, precisa pensar em interfaces, injeção de dependências, testes... crie sempre o que realmente precisa, se não tiver muitas regras vai acabar criando uma camada que não vai fazer o que seria o seu propósito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o tratamento da data obedece uma especificação do negócio e foi pedida pelos especialistas do negócio, então deveria estar numa classe de serviço dentro do seu modelo de domínio para ser consumida pelo controlador.

Agora, se o tratamento só existe para adequar a data à especificações do banco de dados, então poderia estar em um helper dentro da camada de persistência, sendo usada pelos repositórios que precisarem.